# How to make a leaderboard command discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have looked all over the web, and couldn't find an answer. I also asked my friend but he didn't know how to do this command. How can I make this level code display in a leaderboard command?
Here is my code:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if not message.author.bot:
        print('function load')
        with open('level.json','r') as f:
            users = json.load(f)
            print('file load')
        await update_data(users, message.author,message.guild)
        await add_experience(users, message.author, 4, message.guild)
        await level_up(users, message.author,message.channel, message.guild)

        with open('level.json','w') as f:
            json.dump(users, f)
    await client.process_commands(message)



async def update_data(users, user,server):
    if not str(server.id) in users:
        users[str(server.id)] = {}
        if not str(user.id) in users[str(server.id)]:
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)] = {}
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['experience'] = 0
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['level'] = 1
    elif not str(user.id) in users[str(server.id)]:
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)] = {}
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['experience'] = 0
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['level'] = 1

async def add_experience(users, user, exp, server):
  users[str(user.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['experience'] += exp

async def level_up(users, user, channel, server):
  
  experience = users[str(user.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['experience']
  lvl_start = users[str(user.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['level']
  lvl_end = int(experience ** (1/4))
  if str(user.guild.id) != '757383943116030074':
    if lvl_start < lvl_end:
      await channel.send('{} has leveled up to Level {}'.format(user.mention, lvl_end))
      users[str(user.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['level'] = lvl_end


@client.command(aliases = ['rank','lvl'])
async def level(ctx,member: discord.Member = None):

    if not member:
        user = ctx.message.author
        with open('level.json','r') as f:
            users = json.load(f)
        lvl = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['level']
        exp = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['experience']
        endXP = (lvl + 1) ** 4

        embed = discord.Embed(title = 'Level {}'.format(lvl), description = f"{exp} XP / {endXP} XP" ,color = discord.Color.green())
        embed.set_author(name = ctx.author, icon_url = ctx.author.avatar_url)
        await ctx.send(embed = embed)
    else:
      with open('level.json','r') as f:
          users = json.load(f)
      lvl = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(member.id)]['level']
      exp = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(member.id)]['experience']
      endXP = (lvl + 1) ** 4
      embed = discord.Embed(title = 'Level {}'.format(lvl), description = f"{exp} XP / {endXP} XP" ,color = discord.Color.green())
      embed.set_author(name = member, icon_url = member.avatar_url)

      await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```

Another thing. Most of the people that comment on my posts nowadays comment about a certain question that has nothing to do with what I'm asking. If you want to bombard me with those comments, go do it in the question, not on this post. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@client.command()
async def leaderboard(ctx, x=10):
  with open('level.json', 'r') as f:
    
    users = json.load(f)
    
  leaderboard = {}
  total=[]
  
  for user in list(users[str(ctx.guild.id)]):
    name = int(user)
    total_amt = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(user)]['experience']
    leaderboard[total_amt] = name
    total.append(total_amt)
    

  total = sorted(total,reverse=True)
  

  em = discord.Embed(
    title = f'Top {x} highest leveled members in {ctx.guild.name}',
    description = 'The highest leveled people in this server'
  )
  
  index = 1
  for amt in total:
    id_ = leaderboard[amt]
    member = client.get_user(id_)
    
    
    em.add_field(name = f'{index}: {member}', value = f'{amt}', inline=False)
    
    
    if index == x:
      break
    else:
      index += 1
      
  await ctx.send(embed = em)
```

here is some code that may help