# Grab a User ID from a dict (Discord.py)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I've been getting the hang of Discord.py lately. Managing dictionaries, bot arguments, all that jazz. To finish off point management in my bot, I want to make a leaderboard. Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65175929/how-to-make-a-leaderboard-command-discord-py), i structured my code slightly differently from them.

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def testboard(ctx, top:int=10):
  total=[]
  total = sorted(total,reverse=True)
  board=discord.Embed(title = f'Top {top} highest awarded monkes.')
  index = 1
  
  if index == top:
      return
  else:
      index += 1
  
  for str in points:
    userid = points[str]
    user= bot.get_user(userid)
    if index==1:
      badge="\U0001F947"
    elif index==2:
      badge="\U0001F948"
    elif index==3:
      badge="\U0001F949"
    else:
      badge="\U0001F539"
    board.add_field(name=f"**{badge}{index}. {user}**",value=(f"{points[str]} points"), inline=False)
  await ctx.send(embed=board)
```

While it does display the points stored in my database, it doesn't do it from greatest to least, and doesn't display the name of the user.
As seen here: [Result](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/852191184189390851/858031243898650634/Screenshot_2021-06-25_13-09-27.png)

I suspect it's because how my dictionary is structured.

```
{"userid": 0, "userid": 8, "userid": 0, "userid": 35, "userid": 11, "userid": 6}
```

Perhaps I can grab the name of the variable? If so, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the username is just showing up as "None" is this portion of the code:

```py
userid = points[str]
user= bot.get_user(userid)
```

If the `str` variable from the for loop is the user id, then the userid variable you are creating here is the point score for that user, not the id itself, so `bot.get_user` returns `None` because it won't find a user with, for example, an ID of 0. Change those lines to the following:

```py
user= bot.get_user(int(str))
```

Secondly, the points are not in order because dictionaries are not ordered at all, so you would have to sort the objects manually. One way to do that is to get the entries of the dictionary, including both the key (the userid) and the value (number of points), sort it by points, and then iterate through it in a for loop:

```py
  for (userid, score) in sorted(points.items(), key=lambda entry: entry[1], reverse=True):
    user= bot.get_user(int(userid))
    if index==1:
      badge="\U0001F947"
    elif index==2:
      badge="\U0001F948"
    elif index==3:
      badge="\U0001F949"
    else:
      badge="\U0001F539"
    board.add_field(name=f"**{badge}{index}. {user}**",value=(f"{score} points"), inline=False)
```

I changed a couple of variable names here, most importantly `str` which is the class name for the string type, so it could potentially cause conflicts. Also, per your comment, the `get_user` method seems to require an integer and won't do conversion automatically.

Comment: So, because using your code didn't work at first. I slightly edited it. The user id was still being read a a string, resulting in it still displaying as "None". So instead, i had it return as a int by doing the following: `user= bot.get_user(int(userid))`. That's about it, thanks! Make sure to edit it in before I confirm this.